# Join two separate nodes into one cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two separate nodes that have indices in Elasticsearch. I want to try to join them, but I fear I can lose some indices. Can I join them into one cluster? If yes, then how?

Comment: you wanna join nodes or index???

Comment: Join nodes with different indices

Comment: Will they reallocate automatically?

Comment: Yes it will allocate automatically..

Comment: Thank you. I found out, missing indices will autorecover into cluster state. P.S it may take some time depending on size of indices. I would suggest not doing anything on this time